# jQuery DataTables: Pagination not rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to use datatable pagination but code doesn't seem to work.

Currently in my view I am seeing "loading..." but no table rendering is happening in FE. parameters is the data that must be sent to the backend code

The response and the javascript code is provided below

Javascript Code

```js
var createPaginationDataTableUI = function (tableID, title, parameters) {
    var url = 'url_here';
    var _tableTemplate = '<table id="myDataTable-' + tableID + '"></table>';
    var _data = GlobalData.getData(),
      _myData = _data.tableData[tableID],
      _tableTemplate = '<h3>' + title + '</h3><table id="myDataTable-' + tableID + '"><thead><tr>';
    for (var i in _myData.data[0]) {
      _tableTemplate += '<th>' + i + '</th>';
    }
    _tableTemplate += ' </tr></thead><tbody>';

    _tableTemplate += '<tr><td></td></tr></tbody></table>';

    $('#dataTable-' + tableID).html(_tableTemplate);
    var newTable = $('#myDataTable-' + tableID).DataTable({
      scrollY: "300px",
      scrollX: true,
      scrollCollapse: true,
      paging: true,
      fixedColumns: { leftColumns: cols },
      ordering: false,
      ajax: {
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        url: url,
        data: parameters
      }
    });
  };
```

JSON response from the backend

```js
//JSON response
[{
 "data": [{
  "Title": "asde",
  "abc": "asd23e",
  "Material": "asdf",
  "Quantity Jan2016 - Dec2016": 12576,
  "Sales Jan2016 - Dec2016": 1
 }, {
  "Title": "asde",
  "abc": "345fs",
  "Material": "dsfvd 3343",
  "Quantity Jan2016 - Dec2016": 16560,
  "Sales Jan2016 - Dec2016": 6
 }, {
  "Title": "asde",
  "abc": "7687",
  "Material": "af asdf",
  "Quantity Jan2016 - Dec2016": 12216,
  "Sales Jan2016 - Dec2016": 1
 }],
 "totalPayloadSize": 539, // Total no. of entries
 "pageFrom": 0, // 1st entry
 "pageTo": 49, // 50th entry
 "pageSize": 50, // no. of entries to be shown
 "pageNo": 1, // 1st page, Pagination
 "monthsIn": [{
  "fMonth": 1,
  "fYear": 2016,
  "tMonth": 12,
  "tYear": 2016
 }]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because the Ajax response contains unexpected entries after the data section. The examples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/) show the expected format of the returned data.